# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing the result of a fetchrequest return from another method

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

I am focussing an (for me) strange issue when trying to use CoreData in swift with XCode 6.4 in an iOS App.

Here is my code:

```
func checkForAnalyts(){
    if let result = fetchAnalyts(){
        print("\n########################################\n")

        print("Analyts Count: \(result.count)")

        print("\n########################################\n")

        print(result)

        print("\n########################################\n")

        if result.count > 0 {
            for analytItem in result {
                print("Fetched Analyt \(analytItem.name) with unit \(analytItem.einheit) and sortOrder: \(analytItem.sortOrder)")
            }
        }
    }
}

func fetchAnalyts() -> [Analyt]?{
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var fReq: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Analyt")

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let store = appDelegate.cdstore
    let coordinator = store.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if  coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

    fReq.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var sorter: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortOrder" , ascending: true)
    fReq.sortDescriptors = [sorter]

    if let result = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fReq, error:&error) as? [Analyt]{
        print(result)
        return result
    } else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

It's strange, that the fetchAnalyts() method retrieves the correct data and prints it including the attributes values (so everything is fine), while the other method checkForAnalyts (which receives the result of the fetchAnalyts() prints the correct count of 6, but prints the result without attribute values (the are marked as "fault") and when trying to access the attributes it gives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) on the [print in the for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS9Zp.png).
So CoreData is not able to retrieve the values of the NSManagedObject Subclass - probably due to a memory management issue?!

[image: This is the console output.]

I tried to assign the result to an instance variable and accessing it from the checkForAnalyts() but same result. As long I am in the method, that actually does the fetchRequest everything is fine. Obviously I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: If you break your print into three statements, one for each field, does it fail on the first or on a particular field?

Comment: It fails on the first - or better: on each of them...

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the issue:

When using the managedobjectcontext from the AppDelegate like this:

```
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

in the "fetchAnalyts" method - everything is fine.

If I do exactly the same, that is done in the AppDelegate to create a managedObjectContext within the method and store it in an variable within the function (as done before), it gives the EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the other method.

My explanation - the managedobjectcontext is released after the fetchAnalyts method returns leading to the release of the objects in the context. Only the Array is "somewhat hanging around"...

If I create a new instance variable within my class keeping the managedobjectcontext created within my function everything is fine as well.

Lesson learned.